# Re-run an ajax call with $ajax object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a little confused about this and I hope some can help explain this to me. Using jquery $ajax I run something like this (the values here are not relevant):

```
$ajax = $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType, 
    success: callBack,
    cache: cache,
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        dir(thrownError);
        dir(xhr);
        dir(ajaxOptions);
    }
  });
```

How can I run this every few seconds? Should I just wrap it in setInterval() or can I use $ajax.done and pass in the ajax call again recursively? I'm not necessarily asking what the best way is just an example of how I could do this.

Comment: Yes, you can use setInterval, but... don't do that. Use setTimeout in the complete callback instead to avoid piling up ajax requests on a slow connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){
      $ajax = $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType, 
    success: callBack,
    cache: cache,
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        dir(thrownError);
        dir(xhr);
        dir(ajaxOptions);
    }
  });
},1000);
```

Please take a look at **web sockets**, it is better than `ajax` if you want it to be called periodically

Comment: It's potentially a damaging answer. Using an asynchronous action in a setInterval can have very bad results if the asynchronous action takes longer than the interval. Just because it works doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: The OP didn't mention how he/she's going to use the code. So you get what you ask for. Moreover, I wrote that he/she can use web sockets as an alternative solution. If you believe that you have better answer you can put it, but if you don't agree with an answer it doesn't mean it's wrong. @KevinB

Answer (score 0):

setInterval

```
var call = function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: type,
   url: url,
   data: data,
   dataType: dataType, 
   success: callBack,
   cache: cache,
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        dir(thrownError);
       dir(xhr);
       dir(ajaxOptions);
    }
}
```

and

```
   setInterval(call, 5000);
```